# CheckBox from Search Page pulling from an INT Column

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, search

I have a slight problem with a search page I've built pulling from multiple fields from a database. The customers I'm building this for wanted to incorporate a checkbox field that, when checked, would pull all occurrences that doesn't have a null in the column, which was set up as an int column. I've been working at this for a couple days now but have been unable to figure it out with all the resources online and on here. Here's a little bit of code with the search page and the query relating to it. I'm not going to give it all since it's a big chunk of code but I'll give the necessary items,

Search.ascx

```
<telerik:CompositeLayoutColumn Span="4" Height="30px">
    <Content>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="cbAnnulledTrips" runat="server" Text="Annulled Trips" />
    </Content>
</telerik:CompositeLayoutColumn>
```

Search.ascx.cs

```
SqlParameter annulledTripsParameter = new SqlParameter("@AnnulledTrips", SqlDbType.Bit);
annulledTripsParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
if (!cbAnnulledTrips.Checked)
    annulledTripsParameter.Value = Convert.ToInt32(0);
else
    annulledTripsParameter.Value = Convert.ToInt32(1);

selectCommand.Parameters.Add(annulledTripsParameter);
```

sp_SearchResults_ByAllFields

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_SearchResults_ByAllFields]
(
    @StartDate varchar(50) = NULL,
    @EndDate varchar(50) = NULL,
    @OccurrenceNumber varchar(50) = NULL,
    @TrainLine int = NULL,
    @TrainID int = NULL,
    @CarID int = NULL,
    @CategoryType int = NULL,
    @OccurrenceType int = NULL,
    @AnnulledTrips bit,
    @TrainOperator varchar(50) = NULL
)

AS

DECLARE @DateFrom DateTime
SET @DateFrom = Convert(DateTime, @StartDate)
DECLARE @DateTo DateTime
SET @DateTo = Convert(DateTime, @EndDate)               

BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SELECT  o.OccurrenceID AS [Occurrence ID],
            o.OccurrenceNumber AS [Occurrence], 
            o.OccurrenceDateTime AS [Occurrence Date], 
            l.TrainLine AS [Train Line], 
            o.TrainID AS [Train ID], 
            o.LeadCar AS [Lead Car], 
            o.Car2 AS [Car 2], 
            o.Car3 AS [Car 3], 
            o.Car4 AS [Car 4],
            op.FirstName + ' ' + op.LastName AS [Operator], 
            ct.CategoryType AS [Category],
            ot.OccurrenceType AS [Type]     
    FROM Occurrence o
    LEFT JOIN Location lo ON lo.ID = o.LocationID
    LEFT JOIN Line l ON l.ID = lo.LineID
    LEFT JOIN OccurrenceCategory oc ON oc.ID = o.OccurrenceCategoryID
    LEFT JOIN CategoryType ct ON ct.ID = oc.CategoryTypeID
    LEFT JOIN OccurrenceType ot ON ot.ID = oc.OccurrenceTypeID
    LEFT JOIN Operator op ON op.ID = o.OperatorID
    WHERE   (OccurrenceDateTime >= @DateFrom OR @DateFrom IS NULL)
        AND (OccurrenceDateTime <= @DateTo OR @DateTo IS NULL)
        AND (o.OccurrenceNumber = @OccurrenceNumber OR @OccurrenceNumber IS NULL)
        AND (l.ID = @TrainLine OR @TrainLine IS NULL)
        AND (o.TrainID = @TrainID OR @TrainID IS NULL)
        AND (o.LeadCar = @CarID OR o.Car2 = @CarID OR o.Car3 = @CarID OR o.Car4 = @CarID OR @CarID IS NULL)
        AND (CASE @AnnulledTrips
                WHEN 0 THEN (CASE o.AnnulledTrips IS NULL)
                WHEN 1 THEN (CASE o.AnnulledTrips IS NOT NULL)
             END)
        AND (ct.ID = @CategoryType OR @CategoryType IS NULL)
        AND (ot.ID = @OccurrenceType OR @OccurrenceType IS NULL)
        AND (o.OperatorID = @TrainOperator OR @TrainOperator IS NULL)
END
```

I gave you the entire stored procedure with what I tried doing in the WHERE clause, but of course, it doesn't seem to work. If you need me to post more code let me know and I will. Everything else works beautifully, but yeah... I didn't realize this was such a challenge... PLEASE HELP!! I'M GOING INSANE!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing this part of your stored procedure

```
  AND (CASE @AnnulledTrips
            WHEN 0 THEN (CASE o.AnnulledTrips IS NULL)
            WHEN 1 THEN (CASE o.AnnulledTrips IS NOT NULL)
         END)
```

to this:

```
AND (
  (@AnnulledTrips = 0 AND o.AnnulledTrips IS NULL)
  OR (@AnnulledTrips = 1 AND o.AnnulledTrips IS NOT NULL)
)
```

And that's based on your current attempt, which I'm not sure meets your initial description of

> a checkbox field that, when checked, would pull all occurrences that
>   doesn't have a null in the column

Because the logic you were trying to implement means that if the checkbox is not checked, then it will pull ONLY records that have NULL for AnnulledTrips.

If that's not what you want, then simply remove "AND o.AnnulledTrips IS NULL" from my code above.

Comment: OH MY GOD!!!! How easy was that, man thanks so much! Yeah I wanted to pull everything, both null and not null, if the check box was unchecked, so I did what you said and removed the "AND o.AnnulledTrips IS NULL" from there and BOOM!!! You're awesome.